# Приём get данных

Tags: php, get

В общем на странице пару функций (вывод статей, разделов, вывод панельки юзера). Где и как лучше сделать обработку принятых данных: общей функцией в начале страницы и использовать глобальные переменные или в этих же функциях вывода? Что в _get вывести и/или что записать в базу и/или авторизация.

Answer (score -3):

Есть такое золоте правило построения любого веб-приложения.

1. Сначала код(php,python) или что там у вас
2. Разметка страницы.

Если у вас есть страница news.py?id=7&cat=2&ref=http://google.com/

То проще начать с тернарного оператора который одной строчкой наделает много дел:

```
$get = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : exit("Не верный адрес");
$q = mysql_query("select * from `news` where `id` = '". $get ."'") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
    $rows[] = $row;
```

самый обычный пример вывода чего-либо

Comment: Только не копируйте этот код, потому как он содержит и самый обычный пример SQL Injection.